# How can I find the angle between cos(x/4) and sin(x/4) over the interval [0,pi]?

Tags: calculus, probability, inner-products

My professor provided me the formula:
$$  
\cos(\theta)= \dfrac{\langle v,u\rangle}{ ||v|| \cdot ||u||}
$$
and asked us to compute the cosine of the angle between $h(x)= \cos(x/4)$ and $k(x)=\sin(x/4)$ on the interval $[0, \pi]$.

He said one can define the inner product of $h$ and $k$ by the integral from zero to $\pi$ of $h(x)k(x) dx$.

Does anybody know how I can approach this problem?

Comment: You know everything you need to know. What don't you understand from here?

Comment: Hint: $\sin\theta\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta$.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure what the formula entails. I haven't taken calculus in two years and I'm reviewing for a course I'm taking now. I solved the integral from one to pi of cos(x/4)*sin(x/4) and got 1. I'm not sure how I'd get the magnitude of the two trig functions. I remember magnitudes involving vector coordinates.

Comment: since your interval is length $\pi,$ the most likely definition of inner product is $$\langle f,g \rangle = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi f(x) g(x) dx  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the integral from one to $\pi$ but from *zero* to $\pi$, since that is the domain of your functions.

The idea is that you are defining an inner product by the formula
$$\langle f, g\rangle:=\int_0^\pi f\cdot g$$
This inner product, defined on a(n infinite-dimensional) vector space of functions, is what allows you to think geometrically. In particular, you can now use this inner product to define lengths (aka norms, aka magnitudes) by $$\|f\|:=\sqrt{\langle f, f\rangle}$$
and angles by
$$\cos\theta:=\frac{\langle f, g\rangle}{\|f\|\cdot\|g\|}$$
This point of view generalizes the familiar dot-product geometry you learned in regular $n$-dimensional space. You should no longer think of your vectors as an ordered list of numbers, though, because the vectors in these spaces have infinitely many "components." But that's okay, because the inner product we defined above doesn't require us to "dot" respective components. Instead of *summing* up the products of the respective components, as we do with the dot product in regular Euclidean space, we now *integrate* the products over an entire interval.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to follow. So since the solution to my integral found me the inner product (1). I can proceed to plug this into my formula for the length. What I have trouble understanding is how the solution for the integral can apply to both functions. So my solution was 1, for the integral, if I plug that into the formula for the length, I'll receive one. Multiply that by the length of g and I'll get one. The angle of cosine at 1 is zero. Where am I not fully understanding?

Comment: To get the magnitude of the individual functions you need to do two new integrals: the inner product of $\cos(x/4)$ with itself and the same with sine.

Comment: Okay, I understand perfectly. Thank you for your patience and your help!

Comment: You're welcome. You can show your appreciation on this site by upvoting answers.

Comment: It says I lack the reputation to upvote! As soon as I get it, I'll come back and upvote you, 100%.